# In Native UWP, How to apply color for a particular character in a string or how to display multi color text in the textbox control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, textbox, xamarin.uwp

My requirement is I like to display some string in the textbox control and I want to apply color for a particular character in a string. For example in the below image my input string is "My Label" and I have set the text color as "Blue". Now I need to display the specific character or string in different color like "My" String in the below image. Please give me a possible suggestion to achieve my requirement.

[image]

Comment: google: TextBlock Run UWP ... note: TextBlock not TextBox

Answer (score 1):

**TextBlock**

A simpler method would be to use `Span` tags within the content of your `TextBlock`, thanks to the beauty of XAML. See the following:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="25">
    I'M RED BY DEFAULT <Span Foreground="Blue">BUT NOW I'M BLUE!</Span>
</TextBlock>
```

[image: Span Tag result]

**TextBox**

You can use a converter to change the Foreground color of the TextBox contents if a certain condition is met (i.e. The char '!' was entered) but this will change the Foreground color of the entire contents, not simply the char '!'

I don't think this meets your requirements, but I'll post some code anyway just in case it helps you on your way to a solution.

Converter.

```
public class CharColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

        String ValueContent = String.Empty;

        String ForegroundColor = "#000000";

        String charValue = "!";

        //check if value is null

        if (value != null)
        {                
            ValueContent = (String)value;
            // Check for the char ! and change foreground colour 
            if (ValueContent.Contains(charValue)
            {
                ForegroundColor = "#e40034";
            }
        }

        return ForegroundColor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBox Foreground="{Binding TextValue,Converter={StaticResource CharColorConverter}}" Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. But in my case, I am preparing a custom control by inheriting the TextBox control in which I need to apply color for a particular character in a string. Since I am not using RichTextBox control I can't apply the above solution So  I need any other possible solution to achieve my requirement using TextBox control.

Comment: Added some code for a TextBox. fairly certain it isn't what you're looking for, but it may help you on your way to a solution.